# Finding a "recovery" sequence for $f$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $f:X\to [-\infty, +\infty] $.

Now we fix a $x\in X$ and we want to find a sequence $(x_j)\subset X$ convergint to $x$ such that
$$\limsup_{j\to +\infty} f(x_j) \le \bar f(x)$$
where $\bar f$ is defined as the **greatest lower semicontinuous function not greater than $f$**, i.e. for every $x\in X$
$$\bar{f}(x)= \sup \{ g(x) : g \mbox{ l.s.c., } g\le f \}.$$

---

**What I have observed** is that if $x$ is a point of of lower semicontinuity of $f$, then I can choose the constant sequence where every $x_j = x$: this way
$$\limsup_{j\to +\infty} f(x_j) = \limsup_{j\to +\infty} f(x) = f(x)=\bar f(x)$$
(where $f(x) = \bar f(x)$ since $f$ is l.s.c. at $x$).

I cannot find a way for when $x$ is not a l.s.continuity point for $f$.

Comment: Choosing $x_j$ such that it is (almost) the maximizer of $f(y)$ w.r.t. $y \in B_{1/j}(x)$ should do the job, since this choice maximizes the value of $\limsup_{j\to\infty}f(x_j)$.

Comment: How sould I make that choice? It is not clear to me

Comment: You take $x_j$ with $f(x_j) \ge \sup\{f(y)\mid y \in B_{1/j}(x)\} - 1/j$.

Comment: If you take the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0) = 0$, and if we want to find the sequence converging to $0$, with your choice it seems like we get that $\limsup f(x_j) = +\infty$ while $\bar f(0) = -\infty$ which does not work with our inequality.

Comment: If we make the same choice but trying to minimize the value? Meaning $f(x_j) \le \inf\{f(y)\mid y \in B_{1/j}(x)\} + 1/j$.